# Switching to InnoDB From MYISAM via phpmyadmin very slow

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have been switching my tables one by one to `InnoDB` on phpMyAdmin. Each table took a max of 30 seconds.

One table is stuck and has taken over 15 minutes (still going).

In the mysql process list, it shows:

status:

```
copy to tmp table
```

info:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` auto_increment = 2446976 ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC
```

Why is this process taking so long?

Can I kill this process? Or should I just let it go? The table is hot so some rows are waiting to be inserted.

The table does have a unique index on a `varchar(30)` column. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It takes long time because MySQL needs to create new table with the new structure , then copy data from old table (MyISAM) to the new table (InnoDB). When all records are copied it will replace the tables.

I don't recommend to kill it, because rollback process (the new table is InnoDB) will take longer. Just wait until it finishes. After ALTER is done the table will be InnoDB in good condition.